# Script without put ran as administrator leaves no file

Tags: windows, scripting, windows-command-prompt

I am trying to run this script as administrator. When I run it without admin rights the log file is save in C:\Windows\System32. I put echo %~dp0 in the script and it echos to the current directory.

```
%~dp0
SC QUERY | FINDSTR "Fax" 
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 SC CONFIG Fax START= DISABLED >> log.txt
```

If I hard set the log file as this:

```
%~dp0
SC QUERY | FINDSTR "Fax" 
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 SC CONFIG Fax START= DISABLED >> C:\logs\log.txt
```

I can get a log in that location. But I only need to run it on machines with issues and I would like to have the file on the USB.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code snippet:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
SC QUERY state= all | FINDSTR "Fax"
REM alternatively: SC QUERY Fax | FINDSTR "Fax"
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 (
    REM Findstr: Wrong syntax
) else (
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
        REM "Fax": A match not found  
    ) else (
        REM "Fax": A match is found in at least one line of the query
        >> "%~dp0log.txt" SC CONFIG Fax START= DISABLED
    )
)
```

Explanation:

- note that `SC QUERY` *without any option* enumerates only *running* services (default `state= active`), see `SC /?`;
- check `IF ERRORLEVEL number` **in descending order** as `ERRORLEVEL number` specifies a true condition if the last program run returned an exit code *equal to **or greater*** than the number specified (i.e. `IF ERRORLEVEL 0` is *always valid*), see `IF /?`;
- `%~dp0` expands `%0` to a drive letter and path (incl. trailing backslash), see `call /?`. Note that `%~dp0` will return the Drive and Path to the batch script, see [Links relative to the Batch Script](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html))
- `>> "%~dp0log.txt" SC …` - see [redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).